# Pass a jquery selector to function as parameter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I pass a jQuery selector to this function? It works fine this way:

```
$("input[name='this_field']").blur(function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    if ( $("#repeat").val('') ) {
        $("#repeat").val(text);
    };
});
```

But when I try it this way;

```
function repopulateFields(target){
    var text = $(this).val();
    if ( $(target).val('') ) {
        $(target).val(text);
    };
}
$("input[name='this_field']").blur(function() {
    repopulateFields("#repeat");
});
```

It doesn't work and throws an error. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because `this` in function `repopulateFields()` is reference to function `repopulateFields()`, not *element* anymore. You have to pass `this` from `blur()` listener too. I've named it `that`.

```js
function repopulateFields(that, target) { 
   // use `that`
   var text = $(that).val();
   if ($(target).val('') ) {
       $(target).val(text);
   };
}
$("input[name='this_field']").blur(function() {
   repopulateFields(this, "#repeat"); // pass `this`
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="this_field"/>
<input id="repeat"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be very carefull with `this` reference scope.

```
function repopulateFields(el, target){
    var text = $(this).val();
    if ( $(target).val('') ) {
        $(target).val(text);
    }
}
$("input[name='this_field']").blur(function() {
    repopulateFields(this, "#repeat");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong is that `$(this)` in the function `repopulateFields()` has no declaration, you need to set `$("input[name='this_field']")` explicitly:

```js
function repopulateFields(target) {
  var text = $("input[name='this_field']").val();
  if ($(target).val('')) {
    $(target).val(text);
  };
}
$("input[name='this_field']").blur(function() {
  repopulateFields("#repeat");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="this_field" />
<input id="repeat"/>
```